# How can I access DOM element via Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I've been reading the documentation on this but it doesn't look clear for me.

I have created a BrowserWindow instance, and navigated to a URL that I do not control.

I want to access a specific value, which if I run it from my browser console, I get a value.

`document.querySelector('input[name="fb_dtsg"]').value`

How can I run this from my JS code to access that DOM element value and manipulate it in my source code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to execute Javascript in the webContents. You could then send an ipc from it AFAIK to send the data back.

```
myWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
    const electron = require('electron');
    const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;

    var myValue = document.getElementById('myId').value;

    ipcRenderer.send('return-data-message', myValue);
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access elements easily by using renderer.js

To access some button click event defined in your markup file like

```
<button id="save">Save me</button>
```

You just need to write the following lines into your renderer.js

```
document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', function() {
    doSomething();
})
```